# What's the best type of diagram to symbolize objects and values of their instance variables?

Tags: visualization, diagram, uml

I want to visualize an situation with a few different objects, their relations and the values of their instance variables. Any idea which diagram type fits best for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object diagram.

It's like a class diagram except the attribute boxes have values.

Also, the lines between objects are "links" not "associations".  They're the actual link (FK, object reference, whatever) not the class of the link.